# SQL nested count query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have these tables:

```
Discussion
----------
DiscussionID (Primary Key)
Name
....

UserDiscussion
--------------
UserID (Primary Key)
DiscussionID (Primary Key)
Participated (Boolean)
Bookmarked (Boolean)
```

and I need to query 2 things:

1. All discussions where a certain user has participated
2. For every participated discussion I need the total count of users who bookmarked the discussion

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT d.DiscussionID, d.Name
FROM Discussion d LEFT JOIN
     UserDiscussion ud ON ud.DiscussionID = d.DiscussionID
WHERE ud.UserID = 1 AND ud.Participated = true;
```

Sample data:

```
Discussion:

DiscussionID | Name |
---------------------
1              First

UserDiscussion:

UserID | DiscussionID | Participated | Bookmarked |
===================================================
    1          1              1              1
    4          1              1              0
```

Output should look like this:

Discussions: [
  {
    DiscussionID: 1,
    Name: "First",
    BookmarkCount: 1
  }
]

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: Is this a `mysql` question or a `postgresql` question? Or are you looking for answers for both systems?

Comment: I updated how output should look like

Answer (score 0):

You can use a in clause with a subqyery ,, and count

```
SELECT a.DiscussionID, a.Name, b.count(*)
FROM discussion a
INNER JOIN  UserDiscussion b 
WHERE a.DiscussionID in (
    SELECT d.DiscussionID
    FROM Discussion d
    INNER JOIN  UserDiscussion ud ON ud.DiscussionID = d.DiscussionID
    WHERE ud.UserID = 1 AND ud.Participated = true
)
AND b.Bookmarked  = true;
group by a.DiscussionID, a.Name
```

Comment: is the `DiscussionID` after the `where` correct, or should it be `d.DiscussionID`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    d.DiscussionID
    ,d.Name
    ,Participated = SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(ISNULL(b.Participated,0) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ,Bookmarked = SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(ISNULL(b.Bookmarked,0) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    Discussion d
    INNER JOIN UserDiscussion ud
    ON d.DiscussionID = ud.DiscussionID
    AND ud.Participated = true;
    LEFT JOIN UserDiscussion b
    ON d.DiscussionId = b.DiscussionId
GROUP BY
    d.DiscussionID
    ,d.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

sound like you have the 1st query the 2d should be like

```
SELECT DiscussionID, count(UserID)
FROM UserDiscussion        
WHERE DiscussionID in (SELECT DiscussionID from UserDiscussion WHERE ud.UserID = 1 AND ud.Participated = true)
      AND Bookmarked = true
GROUP BY DiscussionID;
```

then eventually you need to join them

With the posted correction:

```
SELECT d.DiscussionID, d.Name, BookmarkCount
FROM Discussion d
JOIN UserDiscussion ud ON ud.DiscussionID = d.DiscussionID
JOIN (
SELECT DiscussionID as DID, count(UserID) as BookmarkCount
FROM UserDiscussion
WHERE DiscussionID in (SELECT DiscussionID from UserDiscussion WHERE
ud.UserID = 1 AND ud.Participated = true)
      AND Bookmarked = true
GROUP BY DiscussionID
) ON d.DiscussionID=DID;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write a view for number of times bookmarked

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_times_bookmarked (
  discussion_id,
  times_bookmarked ) AS
SELECT discussion_id, count(*)
FROM userdiscussion
WHERE Bookmarked = true
GROUP BY discussion_id`

Then in your main query, left join to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temp table to get a count of the bookmarks related to each discussion ID

```
select DiscussionID, count(Bookmarked) as 'Bookmarked'
into #Bookmarks
from UserDiscussion
group by DiscussionID
```

then, join it to the final table on DiscussionID and you can use the count as a column.

```
SELECT d.DiscussionID, d.Name, b.Bookmarked
FROM Discussion d LEFT JOIN
     UserDiscussion ud ON ud.DiscussionID = d.DiscussionID
left join #Bookmarked b on ud.DiscussionID = b.DiscussionID
WHERE ud.UserID = 1 AND ud.Participated = true;
```